# I am unable to use neteller API

Tags: curl, cakephp-2.0

```
$accessToken = $this->_netellerAccess();
                  $data_string = '{
                   "paymentMethod": {
                  "type": "neteller",
                  "value": "ashutosh12@avainfotech.com"
               },
               "transaction": {
                  "merchantRefId": "26434256",
                  "amount": 10,
                  "currency": "USD"
               },
               "verificationCode": "234124"
                   }';
                 $token=$accessToken['accessToken'];
                $ch = curl_init('https://api.neteller.com/v1/transferOut');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                    'Content-Type: application/json',
                     "Authorization: Bearer $token"
                        )
                );
               echo $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

{ "error": { "code": "20005", "message": "Duplicate transaction reference" } }
I always get the error like 20005..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that you have already created a transaction with this 'merchantRefId'.

The 'merchantRefId' field should contain an unique value for each transaction you make.

Answer (score 1):

```
"merchantRefId": "26434256"
```

just change that for another random value